# Joining on multiple columns in Linq to SQL with an OR for the EQUALS on

Tags: c#, linq

I cannot find the proper syntax to join a 3rd table using an "OR" when joining 2 tables (T2 and T3) - in the code below - how can I add the "or equals" on the t3 table with 4 different columns ?

```
List<Tuple<Match, Match_Players, Competition>> res = (from t1 in _context.Competitions
 join t2 in _context.Match_Players
 on new { t1.Club_Id, t1.Comp_Id } equals new { t2.Club_Id, t2.Comp_Id }
 join t3 in _context.Matches
     on new { t2.Club_Id, t2.Comp_Id, t2.Team_Id, t2.Match_Id}
     equals new {t3.Club_Id, t3.Comp_Id, t3.Team_Id_Home, t3.Match_Id}
*** OR ****
equals new {t3.Club_Id, t3.Comp_Id, t3.Team_Id_Away, t3.Match_Id}
*** OR ****
where t1.Club_Id == club_id && t1.Comp_Inactive == false                                                                   && t2.UserId == player_id && t2.Player_Starter != 2
select new Tuple<Match, Match_Players, Competition>(t3, t2, t1)).ToList();
```

Thank you for the help - much appreciated

Comment: Looking at your code... so for usage of tuples inside LINQ query you have loaded three tables competely in memory. Do you think it is OK to put `AsEnumerable` for DbSet properties?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv If I do not add AsEnumerable, I have this error: An expression tree may not contain a tuple literal

Comment: So, do not use tuples! you can use anonoymous classes. `on new { t1.Club_Id, t1.Comp_Id } equals new {t2.Club_Id, t2.Comp_Id }`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - I really appreciate the feedbacks. I then get a syntax error on "Join t3" "the type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect"

Comment: It is also known problem, types should be the same in all properties, and property names should be the same, make appropriate cast. But NEVER use `AsEnumerable` in EF LINQ queries if you don't know what is happened.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv the types are the same : string; But since the name are not the same, I can't achieve what I would do in a normal sql statement then correct ? I'll have to create some type of "union" between the 2 then I suppose

Comment: You can correct names `on new { t2.Club_Id, t2.Comp_Id, t2.Team_Id, t2.Match_Id}
     equals new {t3.Club_Id, t3.Comp_Id, Team_Id = t3.Team_Id_Home, t3.Match_Id}`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `or` keyword in `join` clause.
Instead, you can use `or` or `||` in `where` clause to filter out unsatisfying condition.

See also: [LINQ join with OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159022/linq-join-with-or)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I used.
I split the cases of the OR in two results. Since they are of the same types, I use the same syntax as a SQL Statement and use the INCLUDE between the 2 results.

```
List<Tuple<Match, Match_Players, Competition>> res1 = (from t1 in _context.Competitions
 join t2 in _context.Match_Players on new { t1.Club_Id, t1.Comp_Id }
 equals new { t2.Club_Id, t2.Comp_Id }
 join t3 in _context.Matches on new { p1 = t2.Club_Id, p2 = t2.Comp_Id, p3 = t2.Team_Id, p4 = t2.Match_Id }
 equals new { p1 = t3.Club_Id, p2 = t3.Comp_Id, p3 = t3.Team_Id_Home, p4 = t3.Match_Id }
 where t1.Club_Id == club_id && t1.Comp_Inactive == false && t2.UserId == player_id
 && t2.Player_Starter != 2
 select new Tuple<Match, Match_Players, Competition>(t3, t2, t1)).ToList();

 List<Tuple<Match, Match_Players, Competition>> res2 = (from t1 in _context.Competitions
  join t2 in _context.Match_Players on new { t1.Club_Id, t1.Comp_Id }
  equals new { t2.Club_Id, t2.Comp_Id }
  join t3 in _context.Matches on new { p1 = t2.Club_Id, p2 = t2.Comp_Id, p3 = t2.Team_Id, p4 = t2.Match_Id }
  equals new { p1 = t3.Club_Id, p2 = t3.Comp_Id, p3 = t3.Team_Id_Away, p4 = t3.Match_Id }
  where t1.Club_Id == club_id && t1.Comp_Inactive == false && t2.UserId == player_id
  && t2.Player_Starter != 2
  select new Tuple<Match, Match_Players, Competition>(t3, t2, t1)).ToList();

return res1.Union(res2).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**